# ASP.Net MVC: How to show validation message when working multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

i am showing many check boxes in loop and i want when user submit form then user has to select at least one checkbox. if no check box is selected then validation message will show at client side and form will not be submitted.
so here is

### model & viewmodel

```
public class Hobby
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class SampleViewModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select any Hobbies")]
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

### action method code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var SampleVM = new SampleViewModel();

    SampleVM.Hobbies = new List<Hobby>()
    {
        new Hobby(){ Name = "Reading", IsSelected= false },
        new Hobby(){ Name = "Sports" ,IsSelected= false},
        new Hobby(){ Name = "Movies" ,IsSelected= false}
    };
    return View(SampleVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel vm)
{
    ViewBag.IsPostBack = false;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Product p = vm.Products.Where(x => x.ID == vm.SelectedProductId).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.IsPostBack = true;
        ViewBag.ProductID = p.ID.ToString();
        ViewBag.ProductName = p.Name.ToString();
        return View(vm);
    }
    else
    {
        var SampleVM = new SampleViewModel();
        SampleVM.Hobbies = new List<Hobby>()
        {
            new Hobby(){ Name = "Reading", IsSelected= false },
            new Hobby(){ Name = "Sports" ,IsSelected= true},
            new Hobby(){ Name = "Movies" ,IsSelected= true}
        };

        return View(SampleVM);
    }
```

### view code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <b>Hobbies</b><br />
        @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Hobbies.Count(); x++)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected) @: &nbsp; 
            @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected, Model.Hobbies[x].Name) @: &nbsp;
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hobbies, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

so tell me what to change in code as a result validation message will fire if user select no check boxes for hobbies. where i made the mistake or do i need to code in different way to achieve this goal?

please help me with sample code.

thanks

Comment: Hi @Mou , you might take a look at this? It's an example of a custom data annotation for this purpose  -  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74169

Comment: There isn't a built-in way to validate as you describe. So you'll need custom client-side and server-side validation. You might alter your approach so that the checkboxes append to a string list then that can be validated as a required string input.

Comment: @Jasen please post your idea in detail like what u r trying to say.

Comment: You cannot get client side validation for a collection using a `ValidationAttribute` (only server side validation). You will need to write your only client side script to handle the submit event, check the values and if none are selected, cancel the submit and display a message.

Comment: @StephenMuecke u said "You will need to write your only client side script to handle the submit event, check the values and if none are selected, cancel the submit and display a message."  how to achieve it by  `jquery validate and GetClientValidationRules` function. would u post code.

Comment: Read the dupe. You **CANNOT** do it using `GetClientValidationRules` and `jquery.validate`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have seen u given a link. we have to always validate our self when we work with list of check boxes ?

Comment: see this link http://themikehogg.com/post/2012/08/02/CheckboxLists-in-MVC3  they work with chekboxlist and validate using GetClientValidationRules and jquery.validate. does it work if i use CheckboxLists instead of generate check boxes in loop?

Comment: @Mou, That code is breaking a few best practice principals. For example, the HtmlHelper extension method does not use `ModelState`. Its using 2 validation attributes and an additional property to fake the fact you cannot generate the correct `data-val` attributes. And it means you writing 3-4 times as much code as necessary.